# How to optimize the code to fetch batch size data when using feed_dict?

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow

To fetch batch size data, I implement codes as follows:

```
def load_sample(batch_size, f_pos):
    polist = []
    for i in range(batch_size):
        line = f_pos.readline().strip()
        if not line:
            break
        polist.append(line.strip('\n').strip().split())
    data = np.array(polist, dtype=np.float32)
    return data


f = open('file.txt')
batch_size_data = load_sample(batch_size, file)
```

I find the process of loading sample before feeding into dict takes a long time which is around 50s while a whole epoch is 80s.

How to optimize this function and which part of it is time consuming?

Comment: How many lines are in the file you are reading?

Comment: The dataset is 1.27G. And the file is over one million lines @ondrejba

Comment: You could try to pack it into a tfrecords file. Then, you can use multiple threads to feed the records straight into your neural network. Here is a [tutorial](http://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2016/12/21/tfrecords-guide/).

Comment: Thank you. You mean I can pack it into a tfrecord file and use queue for constructing pipeline. But there is a bug in my GPU when using pipeline instead of feed_dect. Could you please give me some advice to reconstruct the function?@ondrejba